# Generalizing parallel algorithms on the number of threads

Tags: multithreading

I have been reading the book [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123705916) and noticed that a lot of the algorithms mentioned assume a fixed number of threads (e.g. the *combining tree* algorithm).  Is there a straightforward way of generalizing such algorithms to a scenario where threads are created and destroyed in an unpredictable manner?

Comment: If this book is worth anything, it should teach you that not all algorithms are created equal, and what places limits on the degree of parallelism. The only way to tell if you can increase the degree of parallelism is to understand the specific algorithm you're working on, identifying parts that would not interfere if they happened at the same time, and make them happen at the same time. There is no silver bullet to increase the degree of parallelism of an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As Zneak has said, there is no automatic way of determining the number of threads for an application. There are some patterns though that can help. The book may talk about some...here is an article that I was recently reading that I liked....hope it is useful for you too. [Ref: Thread pools and Work queues](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/index.html)